# JAVA - Scanner - Error NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I run into an error when I'm running this function. It finds a word in a certain file using Scanner.

Here it is:

```
public static boolean VerifyExistWord(File FileToSearch, String WordToFind) {

    boolean result = false;
    try (Scanner ind = new Scanner(FileToSearch)) {
        while (ind.hasNextLine()) {
            String word = ind.next();
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(WordToFind)) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

But when I execute this, I run into a `NoSuchElementException`.

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-13777"
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)     at
>   TP.FuncoesAuxiliares.VerifyExistWord(FuncoesAuxiliares.java:66)
>     at TP.PesquisaThreaded.run(PesquisaThreaded.java:90)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have compiler errors? If not, please remove this tag.

Comment: Ok!! You have suggestion to resolve this problem?

Comment: You are checking `hasNextLine()` - perhaps it will work if you call `nextLine()` instead of `next()`?

Comment: the statment next() return word, and I compare my word  with this word.
the statment hasNextLine() is necessary to verify if the documento have more lines.

Comment: OK, so use `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()`. I don't know what your requirements are, but it's pretty obvious that your has and get aren't complementary.

Comment: @fipcurren88 you're missing Andy's point: `next()` works with `hasNext()` while `nextLine()` works with `hasNextLine()`. You mixed two different tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there is a *word* to call `next()` on first:

```
if(ind.hasNext()) {
    String word = ind.next();
    ...
}
```